# How to prevent axis/domain adjustments during selection in Vega-lite

Tags: bar-chart, axes, vega-lite, vega

Here is [my variation](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtBmx5CBWhEzU6jJgwhxtUOZjizzDhASQAvMQEYfAJgIAZgA2fwAOf2V-IIAzAE5YkICQuCgfJiYABiQwuETQ7MDtJAB3AnD4qCzlKHCAdih4nLhlHwAWOBD6uFi6oP8mOCYQoLEof3jwyp98gljtBjp-SigIYhAAXyViB1koNTQAbVBSmmV6NB8s8KyleBoyLDQxu5BkbQBrfWFZOEUQM4HMoaLIyGhQAAPCEgWI0OCCZT6VROAGYACeOH+6CcCBwbBKeiU0CQgmxoGUbGQoJhOCQJQQ+iYiwgMC2SlkNCg5JAoKc2mIpORSHRALMcBwV022xASEhNAgMMwdDJ+i2MtFmllZDI2j4qPQEAYjKUcIRSPQxDYgmN-yUGKx+gAjgwkC46GoaKQAXKFUqVdiQAA1a22gAETHRYYAYos6OqlA5BASYWbEfoFktMGjMYHZFTQULpdtTudLqhrrd7nBHs8K1k3h9vlqHYHfnaQEmU+hdSL2SA6QzFagTiBZEgEIHmTY2cSEWlsy3c-o+XZBUTAfs2CCwcOjiBoQBdaWHpRA7eg8Fa6FatMWlRqDut-S4-GEsUHVVazncmGrgVCugqiisSTiShW0pKL6w6gMqmBfiACYgJqoBIDqeoUAaIBGiasLwumlqhpOOaOugLpunBnrelB8owSAcEIQAKmw6iCGGIY2sR9pcp8ADCbAMC4LxKLq5xoLEpK2MWJYgGcFxsvWVb0SUsgQLEBKMiOoBwoI-JMiyMCUCicAAPxhgAFNOrJGY+RxZIeYYADwALxhiixo2U4ACUYaoGGmCLP8Mk6Xp6BWYZxlmeZ7kIJ5cBOa54VxUcPiHj5fkBQwQWnhgewHIuo5yeWYgNkoTZMvSAJsHSUB0JqWSUOEZ5bjuV5QjC0H+vBgYAMrzlATjKOxRHxeZAAybBkGGPWfnAXn9mhur6oGOEAne+hWpxHYkl+sHLugybgjKz5ka67rqMq3oaqm+H3pm8b2vtY4FuOG6dS2AZqpBnbWt22m3RmcbZo9pHPQghZ6MdbDWsq4GjuthFbT66HLfoq2mhphzoAolD+Iq3HdfoHHhuZSA4Dg2hsJC83BQDiO2sjS2YStxprZji6KLjsRop96DE5OFkU2kCpzVsx4yeVS6g0wVM4MmwOApCThCeg4OyPwyDQjKRUKSVbznq1MJdtoN3moDWYkXmL1FkoN6obRXUIQAimdypkhAFkTVNM2kqLMo7TyJ0gId-YIyAm0MyDgbkedVFBUoKF4Wb6D3QrQf5mrQo0X6H2E+g6onkoeoyII3pagHMI3rysjKBKzi10JxbHkAA) of the [Vega-Lite Bike Counts with Dynamic Scale](https://bl.ocks.org/jakevdp/b511d09ed4e2797234bd6236d7b428f7) community example.

When a time span is selected in the middle chart, the bottom charts do on the fly aggregations (sum and quantiles). However, as I move the selection in the middle graph, some fruit may disappear; likewise the X axes keep adjusting. I would like both the fruit and the X axes in the bottom charts to 'freeze' after the chart is initially rendered.

What would be the best way to solve it directly in Vega-Lite?

Comment: For the fruit listing I went directly to the compiled Vega spec and changed relevant domains to `source_0` but I'd prefer a fix directly in Vega lite.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a fixed domain of the y-axis to ensure that it does not change even when some fruits lack observations in the selected range:

```json
"y": {
    "field": "fruit",
    "type": "nominal",
    "axis": {"title": ""}, 
    "scale": {"domain": ["apple", "banana", "lemon", "mango", "orange", "peach", "raspberry", "strawberry"]}
},
```

[image]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtBmx5CBWhEzU6jJgwhxtUOZjizzDhASQAvMQEYfAJgIAZgA2fwAOf2V-IIAzAE5YkICQuCgfJiYABiQwuETQ7MDtJAB3AnD4qCzlKHCAdih4nLhlHwAWOBD6uFi6oP8mOCYQoLEof3jwyp98gljtBjp-SigIYhAAXyViB1koNTQAbVBSmmV6NB8s8KyleBoyLDQxu5BkbQBrfWFZOEUQM4HMoaLIyGhQAAPCEgWI0OCCZT6VROAGYACeOH+6CcCBwbBKeiU0CQgmxoGUbGQoJhOCQJQQ+iYiwgMC2SlkNCg5JAoKc2mIpORSHRALMcBwV022xASEhNAgMMwdDJ+i2MtFmllZDI2j4qPQEAYjKUcIRSPQxDYgmN-yUGKx+gAjgwkC46GoaKQAXKFUqVdiQAA1a22gAETHRYYAYos6OqlA5BASYWbEfoFktMGjMYHZFTQULpdtTudLqhrrd7nBHs8K1k3h9vlqHYHfnaQEmU+hdSL2SA6QzFagTiBZEgEIHmTY2cSEWlsy3c-o+XZBUTAfs2CCwcOjiBoQBdaWHpRA7eg8Fa6FatMWlRqDut-S4-GEsUHVVazncmGrgVCugqiisSTiShW0pKL6w6gMqmBfiACYgJqoBIDqeoUAaIBGiasLwumlqhpOOaOugLpunBnrelB8owSAcEIQAKmw6iCGGIY2sR9pcp8ADCbAMC4LxKLq5xoLEpK2MWJYgGcFxsvWVb0SUsgQLEBKMiOoBwoI-JMiyMCUCicAAPxhgAFNOrJGY+RxZIeYYADwALxhiixo2U4ACUYaoGGmCLP8Mk6Xp6BWYZxlmeZ7kIJ5cBOa54VxUcPiHj5fkBQwQWnhgewHIuo5yeWYgNkoTZMvSAJsHSUB0JqWSUOEZ5bjuV5QjC0H+vBgYAMrzlATjKOxRHxeZAAybBkGGPWfnAXn9mhur6oGOEAne+hWpxHYkl+sHLugybgjKz5ka67rqMq3oaqm+H3pm8b2vtY4FuOG6dS2AZqjKO08pS1LyCOso4DgqpKEwboQwCZIIHIALIGCbBVSpZAdliSCwACJQQDgQzaNoIHYQFZS4-jIDHjKXbaDd5oZnG2aPaRz0IIWejHWw1rKuBo7rYRW0+uhy36KtpoaYc6AKJQ-iKtx3X6Bx4bmUgwPaGwkLzcFt0bSN-NLZhK3GmtouLookuxGin3oPLk4WTgeq1bY6vkwooDlUujNMKrIMsQCcCQk4QnoMzsj8Mg0IykVCklW856tTClPUwRsJ0yReYvUWSg3qhtFdQhACKZ3KmSEAWRNU0zaSc39j9SpPYd-Y8yAm22inzoFx6l1BUoKF4TT6D3fT9FPfmQdCjRfofbL6DqieSh6jIgjelq1fXiusjKBKzjr0JxbHkAA)

Comment: I did exactly that as a quick work-around in the prototype. However, the list of the fruit name is not known in advance so a solution that could avoid hard-coding would be nicer.